# jQuery slideToggle without the elements animating

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I want to use the jQuery method `.slideToggle` on a div without its content animating, but I can't seem to get that working. All the elements inside that `div` move when I use `.slideToggle` on it, including the arrow (which I don't want moving). Please check out my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ch4jmqz8/

This is the JS code I am using:

```
$('#tgl').on('click', function () {
    $('.toggled_div').slideToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggled_div {
    background: #3597FF;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.toggled_div:before {
        content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    margin-top: -34px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #3597FF;
}
.toggled_div div {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You're using `.slideToggle()`, but you don't want the animation?

Comment: @Sam the problem here is not the container. my problem is with the  elements inside it i don't want them to move. for example the arrow. if you see the fiddle you will notice how he act while toggling the div. i want to keep the slide up and slide down but i don't want the arrow to be like that. i want it to stick with the container

Comment: does it have to be with javascript?

Comment: no it's not necessary to be with Javascipt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's a pure CSS solution where instead of a `div#tgl` we can make use of the pseudo selector `:checked` of a `checkbox`, also we need to hide the checkbox with `display:none` and relying on on clicking its `label for=""` to toggle the transition.

As the hidden `checkbox` gets `checked` status by its `label` , this  `#toggle:checked ~ .slider` condition will be applied and we change the `max-height` property to `200px` instead of its original value `0`, and this property is the one which will be affected by this `transition: all 1s;`

As the transition line animates the `max-height` property, the rule of this `overflow: hidden` in the `.slider` will reveal content as the transitioned `max-height` value changes, same above is said about when the `checkbocx` status changes to unchecked.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bvow11ts/2/)

```css
.toggled_div {
  background: #3597FF;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.toggled_div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #3597FF;
}
.slider {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#toggle {
  display: none;
}
label[for="toggle"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .slider {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">toggle</label>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="toggled_div">
    some text here
    <br>some text here
    <br>some text here
    <br>some text here
    <br>some text here
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of this.  This is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Use `toggle` instead of `slideToggle`.

```
$('.toggled_div').toggle();
```

If you want to use `slideToggle` try below. Hope this will help.

```
$('.toggled_div').slideToggle(0);
```

**Update**

You may need this https://jsfiddle.net/ch4jmqz8/1/.
Just set a height to `toggled_div`.

Comment: or change the `slideToggle` to simple `toggle`

Comment: i want the container to slideToggle without the elements inside the container moving .

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

As OP requested a smooth transitioned toggle with the triangle.

The `:before` is replaced with a div that contains a blue triangle font, so now it can be targeted and manipulated like any other element. There is no extra JS and no complex CSS animations.

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/bq85g8mt/

```js
$('#tgl').on('click', function() {
  $('.toggled_div, #tri').slideToggle(800);
});
```

```css
.toggled_div {
  background: #3597FF;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#tri {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 30px;
  color: #3597FF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tgl">toggle</div>
<div id="tri">▲</div>

<div class="toggled_div">
  some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>
</div>
```

---

Use `.toggleClass` with `.hide { display: none; }` and `.show { display: block;}`

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/79o4L4jx/

```js
$('#tgl').on('click', function() {
  $('.toggled_div').toggleClass('hide show');
});
```

```css
.toggled_div {
  background: #3597FF;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.toggled_div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: -34px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #3597FF;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tgl">toggle</div>
<div class="toggled_div hide">
  some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>some text here
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the slide animation? please read my last above comment

Comment: You said, "I want to toggle a div without animation", You should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: i was talking about the elements inside the div. please read my last above comment and you will understand what i mean. and  i will edit the question

Comment: "*no complex CSS animations*".. With much respect, how complex do you see this `#toggle:checked ~ .slider {max-height: 200px;}` with this `transition:all 1s;` ???.. also using jQuery -*not all js, jQuery in particular*-animation is *slower* than CSS animation, if you were using raw javascript smartly or some other libraries like [Greensock GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) or [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/) for example then JS animation is identical or a little better than CSS animation.

Comment: Also in other cases, JS has another advantage is you can address any element on the DOM to animate it while this is not a possibility with CSS it has to be the sibling or the very next element, but in the OP case it just works fine because it is after it, also the triangle with the div as well as the div's content look odd when you animate them

Comment: I attempted for a solution with as little change to the original code. Every time I go an alternate route I get crap from someone. If you imagined me referring to you in anyway, you should be little less sensitive, with all due respect.

Comment: First: I've already asked in a comment if this has to be done with jquery adn the OP declared as no it doesn't have to, and we give different solution the OP selects what suits him more.

Comment: Are you still carrying on? Too much unnecessary noise IMHO. Btw, anymore comments are upon def ears. By all means have a convo with yourself.

Comment: Second: This is not crap, we all here to learn and share, what I said is not an opinion, it is real facts, jQuery animation depends on CPU  where others works with GPU. beside using javascript to achieve simple animation like changing width, height or skew or rotate or opacity is trivial

Comment: LMAO@ too much noise, this is a knowledge share network and I just shared what it is truth? also I started by "with much respect" while yours was "I get crap from someone"?

Comment: Once again you taken things out of content, I said "Every time I go an alternate route I get crap from someone." because you are so high strung you assumed I refered to you. If you recall I had said previously that I tried to stay as close to the original code. Reread and comprehend. Not everything is about you.